что указать в CN и DNS полях при настройке SSL в kafka, если используется несколько серверов?
Всем привет! Возникла проблема с пониманием настройки SSL в Kafka. Пользуясь туториалом с ютуба, накатил кафку локально из трех брокеров-контроллеров на крафте, настроил SSL. При создании keystore указал dns:localhost и в CN localhost:
keytool -keystore kafka.broker0.keystore.jks -alias broker0 -validity 3650 -genkey -keyalg RSA -ext SAN=dns:localhost -dname "CN=localhost, OU=Home, O=Home, L=Bishkek, ST=Bishkek, C=KG"

Все работает, вопросов нет.
Но основная задача состоит в том, чтобы сделать аналогичные настройки на кластер из нескольких машин с разными ip. Как новичок, сразу скажу, что, возможно, что-то не так понимаю. DNS никаких не задано для машинок. Как я понимаю, машины обращаются друг к другу, и логично указать вместо dns ip адрес, но, как я ни пробовал, все безуспешно: писал ip в dns, вместо dns писал ip:..., но безрезультатно.
Товарищи, подскажите, что делать?
